# Missing path helper for Polymorphic association rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have looked at many tutorials and what not on how to create a polymorphic association in rails but can't seem to get it working. As of now I am following [Ryan Bates tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) on polymorphic association and I keep getting the error undefined method for

I a trying to add tags to my blog post and do not want to use a plugin

I am getting the error

```
undefined method `tags_path' for <class>
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :blog do
  resources :tags
end
```

_form.html.erb for tags

```
<%= form_for([@taggable, @tag]) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

blog.rb

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable
 end
```

Migration file

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :taggable_type
      t.integer :taggable_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
     drop_table :tags
  end
end
```

tags_controller.rb

```
  def index
   @taggable = find_taggable
   @tags = @taggable.tags
  end

  def find_taggable
      params.each do |name, value|
          if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
              return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
          end
      end
      raise ActiveRecord:NoRecord.new("Couldn\'t find it captain!")
  end
```

Comment: What version of Rails? That tutorial is almost three years old, which is a long time in Rails-time. The best guide for this I know of is the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which covers polymorphic associations but is worth reading in its (short) entirety.

Comment: rails 2. Also i know it is old but some of the concepts are the same as in rails 3 just trying to figure out why the error is appearing. Ill check out the link you have sent I have only looked in the rails api so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a polymorphic_url, [details](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url)

```
polymorphic_url([@blog, @tag])
```

or just use a tagging gem like https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: is @taggable defined in your controller, because the same would happen if it was nil.

Comment: If i used the above i would not be able to add tags to photos videos etc. Yes @taggable is defined in my controller. I have updated my code above.

Comment: Figured it out. In my controller I needed to add `@taggable = find_taggable` above `@tag = Tag.new` and everything worked fine.